# Plotting count values over time for specific country names with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linechart

I have a dataframe, df, containing information about a company, the country they are located in, and the year they were founded. I now need to plot the development of the amount of companies founded per country for each year in the dataset (between 1995 - 2015) in a line, however all I manage to create is a pie chart with the total companies funded per country, but not including the year_founded information.

The data looks like this:

| Company | Country | Year_founded |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | USA | 1996 |
| B | NLD | 2004 |
| C | CAN | 2014 |
| D | USA | 2000 |
| E | NLD | 1999 |
| F | CAN | 2000 |
| etc. |  |  |

Ideally I would like to plot the total amount of companies per country in a line chart with different lines per country.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Try computing the CDF of the distribution of times companies were founded for each country, then plotting it by country in a line chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `crosstab` and `plot.line`:

```
ax = pd.crosstab(df['Year_founded'], df['Country']).plot.line()
ax.set_ylabel('Number of founded companies')
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

output:

[image]

crosstab:

```
Country       CAN  NLD  USA
Year_founded               
1996            0    0    1
1999            0    1    0
2000            1    0    1
2004            0    1    0
2014            1    0    0
```

Comment: Ah I did not know this function existed, but this works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupby` and `reindex` so that all years from 1995-2015 are in your graph:

```
data = df.groupby(["Country", "Year_founded"])["Company"].count().unstack(0).reindex(range(1995,2016)).fillna(0)

>>> data.plot()
```

[image]

```
>>> data
Country       CAN  NLD  USA
Year_founded               
1995          0.0  0.0  0.0
1996          0.0  0.0  1.0
1997          0.0  0.0  0.0
1998          0.0  0.0  0.0
1999          0.0  1.0  0.0
2000          1.0  0.0  1.0
2001          0.0  0.0  0.0
2002          0.0  0.0  0.0
2003          0.0  0.0  0.0
2004          0.0  1.0  0.0
2005          0.0  0.0  0.0
2006          0.0  0.0  0.0
2007          0.0  0.0  0.0
2008          0.0  0.0  0.0
2009          0.0  0.0  0.0
2010          0.0  0.0  0.0
2011          0.0  0.0  0.0
2012          0.0  0.0  0.0
2013          0.0  0.0  0.0
2014          1.0  0.0  0.0
2015          0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: groupby + count + unstack is just a nasty way to do a crosstab :p

Comment: You already have `crosstab`. Just an alternative

Comment: I'm assuming this does essentially the same as the crosstab function? This is a very good approach, thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Nick this is also reindexing to add one year before and after in order to have a prettier graph ;)